# error while using pop function in the following program

Tags: python-2.7

In the following program all those lists which are equal to `b` are getting popped.

```
a = [2,4,3,2,4,7,8]
c = a
b = c
b.pop(2)
print a
print b
print c
```

According to me only `b` should be popped but `a` and `c` are also getting popped. Why?

Comment: where is the code for pop()

Comment: In addition to Lubomir's answer, you can do what you expected to happen by using c = copy.copy(a) etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you assing a list from `a` to `c`, you are not creating a copy of the list, just a reference to an existing value. At the point where you run `pop` all of `a`, `b` and `c` are just different names for the same list. You can verify this by comparing `a is c`.

See [this visualization](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a+%3D+%5B2,4,3,2,4,7,8%5D%0Ac+%3D+a%0Ab+%3D+c%0Ab.pop(2)%0Aprint+a%0Aprint+b%0Aprint+c&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish have a copy of a to c and C to b but not a reference:

```
   a = [2,4,3,2,4,7,8]

   # copy a to c
   c = a[:]
   b = c[:]
   b.pop(2)
   print a
   print b
   print c
```